# eclipse 3.7 M7 ADT plugin error

Tags: android, eclipse

tried upgrading to 3.7_M7 of eclipse and the ADT plugin install fails. I dont know who owns the ADT process other than google?

fail details :

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.100.v201011172300.
http://mirrors.xmission.com/eclipse/releases/indigo/201105060900/aggregate/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration_1.2.100.v201011172300.jar.pack.gz

mirror used for ADT plugin:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

to resolve will revert to previous eclipse version

Comment: It looks like the metadata of wst repository is out of date. You could force refreshing the wst repository in the preference - available software site.

Answer (score 0):

Most third-party plugins (those that are not part of eclipse.org) do not track non-final Eclipse releases. Many take weeks or months after Eclipse release to deliver a compatible version.

Check compatibility documentation provided by the plugin provider and do not install non-final versions of Eclipse unless you have a good reason to (such as if you are plugin developer).